# Left cosets of $A_6$ in $S_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Which may be the all of left cosets of $A_6$ in $S_6$?
$\{A_6,(156)A_6\},\{A_6,(34)A_6\},\{A_6,(42)(35)A_6\}, \{A_6,(46523)A_6\}$ or $\{A_6\}$

I dont understand why the answer is $\{A_6,(34)A_6\}$ .I know if we multiply $A_6$ elements in $S_6$ with $A_6$ we get $A_6$ itself. why  multiplying $S_6-A_6$ element with $A_6$ is equal to $(36)A_6$?

Comment: Hint: $aH=H$ iff $a \in H$

Comment: $A_6$ consists of the even permutations of $S_6$. To get anything outside of $A_6$ you need a coset of an odd permutation. Because half the permutations are even, you get all the odd permutations in a single coset.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen is it same with i.e $(1453)A_6?$

Comment: Yes. That's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A_{6}$ is the group of all even permutations of $6$ elements. If you multiply that set by an even permutation, you get $A_{6}$ back, but if you multiply by any odd permutation you get every odd permutation (you need to prove that every distinct even permutation is sent to a distinct odd permutation). So the problem is just: which of those 5 permutations is odd? I leave that to you.

Answer (score 2):

There are only two cosets of $A_6$ in $S_6$, since the alternating group $A_n$ has index $2$ in $S_n$ for any $n>1$.

It has index $2$ because  $A_n$ is the kernel of the *signature* morphism: $\;\varepsilon\colon S_n\to \{+1,-1\}$. Hence $A_n$ is normal in $S_n$, and these cosets are left as well as right cosets.

The cosets are, namely:

- $A_n$ itself; its  elements have signature $+1$;
- the coset of any odd permutation, like the transpostion $(34)$; its elements map to $-1$.